# Is it possible to make a curly brace end in an arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path, tikz-decorations

In the following MWE, I'd like to make the right end of the brace an arrow pointing to the right with an arrow head just like the line below it. Is that possible?

The goal being that the right side of the brace points off to the right horizontally, just as the line below it does.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (10,0);
        \draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
        \draw (1.5,0.2) -- (1.5,-0.2);
        \draw (3,0.2) -- (3,-0.2);
        \draw (4.5,0.2) -- (4.5,-0.2);
        \node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
        \node [below] at (1.5,-0.2) {1};
        \node [below] at (3,-0.2) {2};
        \node [below] at (4.5,-0.2) {3};
        \node [above] at (1.6,0.2) {\$1500};
        \node [above] at (3,0.2) {\$1500};
        \node [above] at (4.5,0.2) {\$1500};
        \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.7) to (10,0.7);
        \node at (5,1.2) {simple ordinary annuity};
        \node at (4,1.8) {$j_1=6\%$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A dirty way to straighten out the end.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (10,0);
        \draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
        \draw (1.5,0.2) -- (1.5,-0.2);
        \draw (3,0.2) -- (3,-0.2);
        \draw (4.5,0.2) -- (4.5,-0.2);
        \node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
        \node [below] at (1.5,-0.2) {1};
        \node [below] at (3,-0.2) {2};
        \node [below] at (4.5,-0.2) {3};
        \node [above] at (1.6,0.2) {\$1500};
        \node [above] at (3,0.2) {\$1500};
        \node [above] at (4.5,0.2) {\$1500};
        \begin{scope}
        \clip(9, 1.5) rectangle (-1, -0.5);
        \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.7) to (10,0.7);
        \end{scope}
        \draw[->] ([yshift=5pt]9, 0.7) -- ([yshift=5pt]10,0.7);
        \node at (5,1.2) {simple ordinary annuity};
        \node at (4,1.8) {$j_1=6\%$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: brace]

Is this what you want?

Comment: That is what I am looking for! Now I just need to understand what you did here haha Thanks! Why is this a 'dirty' way to produce this result?

Comment: I basically clipped the right end of brace and added a line with an arrow. I would love to do this by just manipulating the curly brace ( perhaps some sort of decoration or edge style). Hence the 'dirty' way.

Comment: Does clipping mean that there is like a box around it or something? I ask because I am curious to know if this will leave any tell-tale signs that it was done this way, that is if I start adding other nodes or draw any other lines around it, is it possible they might overlap in any way to make the clipping noticeable?

Comment: Yes, clip creates a rectangle around the brace and anything outside this rectangle gets deleted. But its scope is limited to the brace so it shouldn't affect any other elements.

Comment: @Adarsh: See my answer for a way to manipulate the brace decoration. I obviously advise against my overly complicated solution.

Answer (score 15):

One way is to redefine decoration with this option in place or you can nest decorations with an arrowhead added as a `markings` decoration.

```
    % with \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} in the preamble
    \draw[postaction=decorate,
         decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[blue]{>}}}
         ]
          decorate[decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}]{ (0,0.7) to (10,0.7)};
```

[image]

You can also butcher the existing decoration and cancel the last curvy part

```
\pgfdeclaredecoration{half brace}{brace}
{%
  \state{brace}[width=+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance,next state=final]
  {%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
    \pgfpathcurveto%
    {\pgfqpoint{.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.3\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
    {\pgfqpoint{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
    {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
    {%
      \pgftransformxshift{+\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
      \pgfpathcurveto%
      {\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
      {\pgfqpoint{-.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.7\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
      {\pgfqpoint{0\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
      \pgfpathcurveto%
      {\pgfqpoint{.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.7\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
      {\pgfqpoint{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
      {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
    }%
    {%
      \pgftransformxshift{+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
    }%
  }%
  \state{final}{}%
}
```

If you place it in your preamble you can use it with `half brace` just as you would use regular `brace`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [decorate,decoration={half brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.7) to (10,0.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My apologies, but perhaps I worded the question wrong, I am trying to produce the arrow at the end of the brace such that it points in the same direction as the arrow on the line below it.

Comment: You make it look easy!

Comment: @percusse is it possible to straighten out the end of the brace with the arrow that you added on?

Comment: This is the best answer since it works generally without user adjustment.  That said, I'd hide it deep in a separate preamble or sty file.  ;-)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Along the lines of percusse's answer, you could do something like

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0.0) rectangle(9.5,2.0);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.7) to (10,0.7);
\end{scope}
\path[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.95 with {\arrow{>}}}] decorate[decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] { (0,0.7) to (10,0.7)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is also exactly what I'm looking for. Can there be two right answers? Which one is the right answer?

Comment: If you like them equally well, pick the one that came first.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose for this answer is just to show that it is possible to do with the existing brace decoration. The solution is over complicated for a simple task.

The clipping in other answers is indeed a dirty way to do it. It would be possible to rewrite the brace decoration with `\pgfdeclaredecoration` but that is again over complicated. I believe the best option is simply not to use the brace decoration at all. Just draw what is needed with curves and lines.

---

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\tikzset {decoration={show path construction,
    lineto code={\draw (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);},
    curveto code={
      \draw [->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) --
      (\tikzinputsegmentfirst -| \tikzinputsegmentlast) ;},
}};
\path[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=0.5cm},
postaction={
  draw,
  decorate,
  decoration={curveto, post=show path construction, post length=1cm}
}
] (0,0) -- (4,0);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Brace with horizontal arrow at end]

Comment: Thanks @hpekristiansen . It's a nice approach. It will take me some time to understand the entire code but I think amplitude and post length are important parameters. Especially when size becomes small. For example, I was trying to draw brace between (0,0) -- (1,0) and struggling with choosing the appropriate parameters.